# Flash AS3 stageWidth wrong in Firefox 3.6

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, firefox, window, stage

I have a full-windowed SWF running in Firefox3.6.

Reading stage.stageWidth should follow the size of the browser's window, but that's not the case with Firefox! The minimum stage.stageWidth I get is 925, even if I make the Firefox window much smaller than that. stage.stageHeight seems to work fine though.

This is because the (my?) Menu Bar won't go below 925 pixels wide. The problem is solved if I hide the Menu Bar!

This problem only appears on Firefox. Anyone knows if there is a work around? I can't ask users visiting my site to turn their menu bar off in order to see it correctly.

Comment: This question reminded me of an issue I had before with stageWidth on FF.  Unfortunately I had different problem (stageWidth was 0 when it shouldn't be), but maybe the work around will give you something to try.  Check out item 21 in the FAQ for swfObject: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/faq

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it actually is unrelated to my problem.

Comment: By all means don't post any code.

Comment: I second The_asMan (awesome nick). Otherwise, bootstrap the window width into swfobjects flashvars.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about your question.

If the solution was to make the menu fit on a screen with less than 925 pixels --what solves that issue ?

Is the issue that you want the correct stageWidth so that you can resize the menu?

I think we need to talk about what your expectations are for what should happen when a window is less than 925 in width(the width of the menu). Should it scale and maintain proportion ?

If that's the case - then we should be talking about the scaleMode property of the stage right ?

I understand that there might be a bug with FF involved, but knowing your current scaleMode setting would be helpful. Knowing exactly how you are embedding it on the page and settings there as well.